# onDestroy для айфон и переход в системные настройки приложения

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

Eсть два вопроса, не знаю как правильно задать их в гугле, чтобы он вывел корректные ссылки:
1. Можно ли после закрытия программы(именно закрытия) отправить локальный нотификейшин. На андроиде например, если пользователь закрывает программу, то есть блок onDestroy(), где можно вызвать свой блок кода перед завершением программы, это может быть также notification;

2. Можно ли напрямую из программы перейти в эту настройку телефона?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу второго уже ответили, однако по поводу первого – не совсем так. У UIApplicationDelegate есть метод `applicationWillTerminate(_:)`, который вызывается как раз перед тем, как приложение убивается системой. Вместе с ним через NSNotificationCenter рассылается уведомление `willTerminateNotification`. Либо в реализации метода выше, либо в обработчике указанного уведомления у вас есть шанс выполнить нужные вам действия.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нельзя
2. Можно:

   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)